# Changing the numbers in "[#number]" format in an MTA file so they are sequential

Tags: notepad++, regex, find-and-replace, mta

I have a very long MTA file for scripting MP3 tag changes.

I've edited the file numerous times in Notepad++ and this has caused the numbers for each particular action to go out of sync.

How could I use Notepad++ to find each instance of '[#number]' and replace the content incremented by one each time it finds a match, starting from the beginning of the file?

The process would have to strictly find matches like the example given to avoid other code being edited within the file.

[image: Example screenshots]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot 'add one' with a regular expression with notepad++.

However, this workaround may work for you:

1. Clean the numbers first: Replace `\[#\d+\]` by `[#]`
2. Replace new lines with something that cannot be repeated inside the file: For example, replace `\r\n(?!\r\n)` by `<<<EOL>>>`
3. Fix first line (insert the number by hand)
4. Use column editor for the rest of the columns. Place the cursor on the second line, after the '#' and press ALT+C
5. Select "Number to insert": Initial number => 2, Increase by => 1.
6. Select "Leading zeros"
7. OK => This will add the numbers
8. Replace `\[#0+(\d+)\]` by `[#\1]`
9. Now restore the end of lines: replace `<<<EOL>>>` by `\r\n`

Note: I'm assuming windows line ending. You may need to use `\r` for Mac or `\n` for linux.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will be testing this shortly but wondered if there was a way to convert this into a script within Notepad that can be run either with a prompt in the middle to do the manual work or as two scripts dealing firstly with steps 1-2 and 4-8?

Comment: You can use the record macro functionality. However it seems you cannot record "Column editor" in the macro. So you'll probably want to record 1-3 and 5-8 and assign some shortcuts to them. Then: 1) call first macro, 2) manually call column editor (alt+c), 3) call second macro

Comment: Thanks for replying. I just started testing this and everything you say works fine until I get to the end. I notice all numbers which from 1 to 9 contain an extra space after them like '[#1 ]' once put back together at the end. How do I fix this as part of the macro please?

Comment: I just added another step. Just use 'leading zeros' and then remove them. For the macro use steps 1-3, alt+c, and then 5-9

Comment: It looked good until I checked the code. Now I have a problem with most lines:

[#77]
T=2
F=_DIRECTORY
1= (Digital Album)
2=
3=0|0

Line 3 it has added "|0" which did not exist before. How do I fix this as part of the macro please?

Comment: That  additional "|0" doesn't make much sense. I'm just wondering if it could be a typo when recording the macro. May I ask you to upload the file (or part of it) somewhere so I can test it on my machine?